# Uglify JS - remove only console.log

Tags: javascript, webpack, uglifyjs

I have a question regarding the `Uglify JS` module, in the usecase of webpack plugin.

My codebase have several `console.log` statements around the code for debugging purposes localy, it will only be printede out in development mode, but they are still taking up space in the codebase and i dont what them in the production build but, i would like to keep my `console.error` and `console.warn` still.

I know the `Uglify JS` have key `drop_console` flag but that kills every console output there is and i still want the warnings and errors in my console.

The reason for this question is i have a custom error handler than ships errors to Sentry, and I want to read the error in the console when it happens, so i use the error and warning console out put.

Comment: I think your approach is wrong. you should never commit `console.log` statements to a repo in the first place (unless writing some api or node based service). Your eslinter should give you a warning as soon as you have `console.log` in your code that way you never commit it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [docs](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#compress-options):

> `drop_console` (default: `false`) -- Pass `true` to discard calls to `console.*` functions. **If you wish to drop a specific function call such as `console.info` and/or retain side effects from function arguments after dropping the function call then use `pure_funcs` instead**.
>
> ...
>
> `pure_funcs` (default: `null`) -- [...] You can pass `pure_funcs: [ 'Math.floor' ]` to let it know that this function won't produce any side effect, in which case **the whole statement would get discarded**.

So the option you're looking for is `pure_funcs: [ 'console.log' ]`

Comment: Ahh great! I just did not understand the pure function explanation of the docs, thanks for makeing it more clear to me :)